# Get access to the ORB into an implementation?

Tags: java, corba

I have a tricky problem. And being new to CORBA, I'm unable to get out of it.

How can I instantiate an implementation object from another implementation?

Usually, if I have an interface A. I would create an A_Impl class (in a A_Impl.java file), extending from the A_POA class generated from the idl.

Then, on the server side I would do something like this :

```
AImpl  my_a_impl = new A_Impl ();
org.omg.CORBA.Object ref = orb.activate_object(my_a_impl);
A my_a_object = A.narrow(ref);
```

But what when one of the methods of another object B needs to return A?

In my B_impl class, I don't have access to the orb and thus cannot get a reference to my object by using the activate_object method.

How can I then return such an object?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should learn the differences between servants and references in CORBA. It's a very important distinction and will help you code your server. Here are two good resources: http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/concepts-for-server-side-programming.html and http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/6.3/develop/corba_pguide/java/ServerBasics1.html

Comment: Thx ! I struggle to find some good stuff on CORBA online that go over the 'tutorial' or 'getting started'. I hope those are some of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like (for a non comprehensible reason for me), constructors are not generated by the idl.
Creating constructors allows me to simply pass objects as references and make them visible to my classes.
Yes... as simple as that :)

Answer (score 1):

CORBA already offers a function that can be used to get an existing ORB reference - `ORB_init()`. For most ORBs, that function behaves like a singleton and will return an existing ORB object, assuming you use the same ORB ID each time you call it.

Comment: Never use the [ORB.init()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/ORB.html#init()) function to create objects. As doc tell "the ORB it returns is restricted so that it can be used only as a factory for TypeCode objects".

Comment: ORB_init() is used to create ORB objects, or find them if they don't exist. I'm not saying he should use it to create his servant objects (that's his own responsibility).

Comment: So it cannot activate an object with `orb.activate_object(`.

Comment: Sure, but he must use the ORB reference to get the POA reference in order to activate his object. Alternatively, he could use `_this()` to do implicit activation.

Answer (score 0):

Put a reference to the current active orb in a singleton class, that you can reach from very object `*_Impl`.